# SecureSocket connection using self signed certificate

Tags: flash, ssl-certificate, ssl

I'm trying to communicate with a SSL server (in Node.js) using SecureSocket in flash. It works fine to "telnet" to the server using

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1337
```

So the server seems to be working. But when I try to connect with a flash client it doesn't work. What happens is that the server detects a connection which closes immediately without any data sent. On the client side it takes a little while, then the SecureSocket instance dispatches an error event.

I'm loading a certificate in the client using addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate, and I have tried to pass both true and false as second parameter to that function.

The certificate is in DER format, converted from PEM using:

```
openssl x509 -in input.pem -inform PEM –out output.der -outform DER
```

As described here: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106631

Don't know what next to try... Btw, the certificate is self signed, is that a problem? I'm thinking it would work anyway, since I'm calling the addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate method.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful, perhaps, to explain what the error message/error event is saying.

Comment: Yeah that's a good suggestion.. :) let me check tomorrow..

Comment: @MikaelLindqvist it's far easier to debug with wireshark if you own the server private key. You can decrypt (well, if the handshake isn't TLS 1.2) and look for the TLS alert messages if it has anything to do with TLS.

Comment: Tried to print out the error message now. It's not very informative, it just says "Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://localhost/xyz.swf cannot lod data from localhost:1337" (However, it's not a "sanbox violation" in the usual flash sense, since it works fine if I use a normal Socket, it definitely has something to do with it being a SecureSocket).